# Necessary things in LPC1343 basic development board

Tags: microcontroller, design, arm, cortex-m3, lpc

I have finished my LPC1343 basic development board,just based on specs from datasheet and some referred from microbuilders.eu.  I'm unsure if the board design is good or not so I've attached my schematics.  Some things I'm concerned about are:

  1.Power supply

  2.D+ and D- from usb through 33 ohm resistor to chip and additional usb softconnect if necessary

  3.Testing LED.

  4.Separate switches for RESET and USB ftoggle.

  5.12MHz crystal oscillator with 16 pF caps.

My question: Is the board design is good enough to work or will it go wrong? If something is wrong, what is wrong with it?

[image: overall image of sch]
[image: The reset and usbtoggle switch connections]
[image: The USB section,oscillator and power supply]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGJYO.jpg)
[[image: Tester LED and other pins]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taccr.jpg)

Comment: Which power supply are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that I'd point out:

1) As you noted in the below comments, you are using a diode to buck the voltage from a 3.7V battery.  I've recommended against that since, as they are used, batteries lose their voltage level so your VCC line will vary depending on how much charge is in the battery.  I'd recommend a real power supply over a diode since you'll remove that varied voltage as well as having a real regulated line.  You'll need something with a low dropout voltage or brownout detection since your voltage difference between the battery and your required VCC voltage isn't that large.

2) Your USB resistors are fine.  Just remember that when you lay your PCB out, that USB uses differential signaling.  This means that they need to be length-matched and routed accordingly.

3) LED looks fine

4) Your USB_Ftoggle button isn't necessary.  USB_Ftoggle signal is an output.
[image: USB_Ftoggle signal description]

5) Your crystals capacitors.  You have 16pF in place and I'm curious where you got those values.  The [LPC1343 development board](https://www.embeddedartists.com/products/lpcxpresso/lpc1343_xpr.php) uses 18pF for its 12MHz crystal, which is also recommended in the [LPC1343 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1311_13_42_43.pdf) in Table 21 on page 61.

One other thing is I'm curious why you have a test point on the D+ signal of your USB but not the D- signal.  You can't really use that for anything.

Comment: Actually for the power supply,I planned to take it from a Li-ion mobile phone battery(3.7V max.).I schematics ,you'll note that I used a diode(assume Vf=0.7).At that point,I will get almost near to 3.0V supply,which I assume that it's sufficient to run controller

Comment: 1.In that schematics,I used a diode(assume Vf=0.7V) and the power source which I planned to use is a Li-ion mobile phone battery(3.7V max.).So at that point I will get about 3.0V(from datasheet I noted limiting value from 2V to 3.6V. 2.capacitors is my mistake,what you told is right which I noticed now. 3.I kept my D+ and D- signal as close as possible to microcontroller  and also with thick signal lines ,without bends.

Comment: from application note AN10986,I saw a line describing(page no 3) "Holding PIO0_1 low during power-up will trigger the on-chip ISP firmware to enter ISP mode (unless it is disabled by the NO_ISP code read protection [CRP] mode). Once ISP mode has been entered, the USB VBUS line PIO0_3 is checked. If high, then USB ISP will be entered." .So I used a button at usb-f toggle. you told that test point at D+,which is actually for USB softconnect.I am not confident on that part.So I just kept it as test point(assuming that its not so necessary)

Comment: Is it correct ,or wrong which I commented @Funkyguy

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that you were using that for ISP flashing.  You should be fine then.  

As for the power supply, I'd recommend using an actual regulator with brown-out support.  Batteries drop in voltage as they are discharged so your battery may start at 3.9/4V but can drop to around 3.4/3.5V as the battery gets low.  Using an actual power supply IC means that you'll get a regulated 3.0V assuming you don't have a brownout on the tail-end of the batteries capacity.  Otherwise your system voltage will swing with the batteries voltage drop if you use a diode.  And diodes have a current limit.

Comment: @Aadarsh I'm not sure how much current you plan on pulling through the diode, but they do have a max current limit and are not meant for in-series voltage regulation.  You could use a AP7331 or if you need a through-hole part MIC29152WT

Comment: Is that D+ and D- line in PCB board is okay which I described?.And moreover the usb softconect part is okay or not?.Does it respond for USB connection for the first time.Because I dont have JTAG link.I only depend on the USB ISP in microcontroller to upload my program.@Funkyguy.

Comment: @Aadarsh I think you should be fine, just make sure you route the traces directly from the USB to the MCU differentially.  As for the soft-connect, I'm worried about your LED.  That circuit is essentially giving the D+ line a current path to ground...which it will most likely take.  I'd recommend removing the LED, resistor, and the connection to ground.  For the soft-connect, you aren't supposed to have the source of the FET connected to ground.  I'm referencing the LPC1343 users manual and http://blog.ilektronx.com/2011/09/all-about-lpc1343-usb-bootloader.html

Comment: @Aadarsh I'm not sure if it'll work right away, although I don't see anything saying it wouldn't either.  I'd say give it a shot and if you do need to use a different way of programming, grab an LPClink2, http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/lpcxpresso/lpclink2.php

Comment: If you have any other questions, come into the chat room:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32681/discussion-between-funkyguy-and-aadarsh